# SQL Server: Check if current day is Sunday

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

In a conditional I would like to check if current day is Sunday independently of the local setting so I have done:

```
DECLARE @IsSunday BIT

SELECT 
    @IsSunday = CASE  
                   WHEN DATEPART(DW, getdate() + @@DATEFIRST - 1) = 7 
                      THEN 1 
                      ELSE 0 
                END 

IF @IsSunday
BEGIN
  // Do some stuff
END
```

I need someone to confirm me that this will work under any local setting, for example, SQL Servers with English configuration and other languages.

In Spanish configuration above code is working.

Comment: My machine have default US setting and it is returning 1 = Sunday      
 select getdate() , DATENAME(dw, getdate()+3), DATEPART(DW, getdate()+3 )                  OUTPUT -  2017-08-31 16:33:46.633 Sunday 1

Comment: `I need someone to confirm me that this will work under any local setting` this doesn't make much sense.you will need to operate under one regional setting

Comment: So how can I make this to work independently of the local setting?

Comment: you can use the SET DATEFIRST 7 command to set sunday as first day of the week, regardless of the regional setting of your sql server

Comment: You can check the day using of DateName function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick any Sunday, for example `20170910`, and calculate the difference in days between that Sunday and the date you need to check.
If the result of modulo 7 is 0 you have a Sunday.

```
select case when datediff(day, '20170910', getdate()) % 7 = 0
         then 1
         else 0
       end;
```

Comment: but in this case I need two dates and I only will have one, the current date

Comment: @user1624552 `2017-09-10` should be hardcoded in the query and never changed.

Comment: @user1624552 You can of course select any sunday you want as long as you are sure it is a sunday. You could replace 20170910 with for instance 18991231 which also happens to be a sunday.

Comment: ah ok, sorry, yes you are right. This works! thanks! and it is independent of the local setting, english, italian, spanish. All languages work then because you are performing a difference based on days.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DateName function in sql server. For more detail please refer the below query.

```
DECLARE @IsSunday BIT
SELECT @IsSunday = CASE WHEN UPPER(DATENAME(DW, getdate())) = 'SUNDAY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 

IF @IsSunday
BEGIN
  // Do some stuff
END
```

Comment: in other languages the sunday might be called something else.Run this query 'select days from sys.syslanguages'

Comment: It depends on your current language, which you can get using select @@language. So 'select days from sys.syslanguages where name = @@Language' will get you the names in the current language

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
DECLARE @DATEFIRST int = @@DATEFIRST; -- Get the current first day of the week
SET DATEFIRST 7; -- Set the first day of the week to sunday (U.S default)

SELECT  CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) = 1 THEN -- If the weekday is 1 it's Sunday
            1 
        ELSE 
            0 
        END As IsSunday;

SET DATEFIRST @DATEFIRST; -- set the first day of the week to back it's original value
```

Of course, If you don't want to set the [`datefirst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql) back to it's original value, you can simply set it to 7 and remove the first and last rows of the code.

Also, I've tested your original code and it seems to be working fine:

```
DECLARE @i int = 1

WHILE @i < 8
BEGIN

SET DATEFIRST @i;

SELECT CASE WHEN (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2017-08-27') + @@DATEFIRST - 1) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 


SET @i = @i + 1

END
```

Returns 1 every time.

Comment: And is there any way to avoid to touch @@DATEFIRST and then back to original value?

Comment: Yes, I've edited my answer. However, I think GuidoG's answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

compare the daynumber of your date with the day of a known sunday

```
declare @IsSunday bit
Declare @yourdate date = '20170820'

select @IsSunday = case when datepart(dw, '20170827') = datepart(dw, @yourdate) 
                     then 1 -- sunday
                     else 0 -- not sunday
                   end

IF @IsSunday
BEGIN
  -- Do some stuff
END
```

where '20170827' is a known sunday and is a constant which you should not change

Comment: If it works and helps you, then consider giving it an upvote